# An MA model has MA characteristic polynomial $(1 − 1.4x + 0.3x^2 )(1 + 0.5x^{12})$, obtain the model

Tags: autocorrelation, moving-average, characteristic-function

When the characteristic polynomial of a moving average s model is given as  $(1 − 1.4x + 0.3x^2 )(1 + 0.5x^{12})$, how to obtain the MA model and then calculate the ACF of this model?

I am expecting an explanation of how to solve this type of problem.

Comment: Is this an assignment? If so, please check out the protocol for `self-study` questions.

Comment: @NickCox, no. This is a practice question. I need help understanding how to solve this and similar questions.